# split String in an array

Tags: java, arrays

Thanks for reading this. I'm currently making a phonebook project which required me to use only one array to store values. My question is how can you split a String inside of an array into two value? So I can search someone's name and get their name and number.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: instead of saying something to OP, i would like to ask moderators to temporarily block the accounts of all those who has answered for easy rep...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the String#split method on any element of the array, whose delimiter can be any character.  Here is an example where I chose : to be the delimiter.

```
String[] information = { "Castiel Li:123-456-7890" };

String[] args = information.split(":");

String name = args[0];
String phoneNumber = args[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have an array like the following:

```
String[] records = {"Bob, 1", "Mary, 2", "Castiel, 3"};
```

Then you can iterate over the record array in a loop and apply the String#split() method to each String object. In this case, the delimiter (character that separates tokes) in each string is the ',', so for a given String "name, number", you'd do:

```
String[] oneRecord = records[i].split(',');
```

Where `oneRecord[i]` would contain the two String objects "name" and "number"

Comment: So what would oneRecord stores? the first half of the string?

Comment: @CastielLi I'll edit with clarification. Also, would you clarify how your program is receiving the input, and whether your final array needs to be one-dimensional, specifically? You can use the logic I described to get the desired result, but it all depends on exactly what you wish to achieve.

Comment: I think I got it. The final array will be one-dimensional and the program does receive input. I just wasn't sure how to split a string inside of an array. I think I will just use local variable to compare with the user input and the database

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given sample inputs and outputs. But I think you are saying that you are storing the phone book in a single dimension array like following:

`String[] array = {"Abc123", "xyz234", "pqr343"};`

You can try something like following:

```
String phone1 = array[0].replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
String name1 = array[0].replaceAll("[0-9]", "");

System.out.println(name1 + " " + phone1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps that use [str.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String phoneBook[] = new String[2];
    phoneBook[0] = "John 1234567";
    phoneBook[1] = "Max 2345678";

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(phoneBook));

    for(String contact : phoneBook)
       System.out.println("Name: " + contact.split(" ")[0] + " Phone Number: " + contact.split(" ")[1]);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[John 1234567, Max 2345678]
Name: John Phone Number: 1234567
Name: Max Phone Number: 2345678
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/FGyl/0)